# How to delete last object of an input array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I created a dynamic form which adds 3 new input fields if the user clicks a button. However, my delete button deletes the first added fields, which I don't want. How can I delete the last added input fields?

Below is my code for adding and deleting the fields.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 0; //initial count
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div id="names">Name: <input type="text" name="names[]"/></div>');
        $(wrapper).append('<div id="ages">Age: <input type="text" name="ages[]"/></div>');
        $(wrapper).append('<div id="numbers">Number: <input type="text" name="numbers[]"/><br><br></div></div>');
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_person", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x > 0) {
            $("#names").remove();
            $("#ages").remove();
            $("#numbers").remove();
            x--;
        }
    })
});
```

Below is my code for the fields in the HTML.

```
<b>People:</b><br>
<div class="input_fields_wrap" id="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">ADD</button>
    <button id="remove_person" class="remove_person">REMOVE</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: check .last() api - https://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: Use unique ids (maybe based on the value of `x`)

Comment: You need to have IDs be unique. To delete, use  `closest` to remove the wrapper the button is in (so have a wrapper for each person)

Comment: @H77 Hmm the problem with that is that when 1 is deleted another could have the same ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, You're using duplicate id's. please use class names instead.

use the jquery's last function like below

```css
$(document).ready(function () {
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 0; //initial count
    $(add_button).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="names">Name: <input type="text" name="names[]"/></div>');
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="ages">Age: <input type="text" name="ages[]"/></div>');
        $(wrapper).append('<div class="numbers">Number: <input type="text" name="numbers[]"/><br><br></div></div>');
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_person", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x > 0) {
            $(".names").last().remove();
            $(".ages").last().remove();
            $(".numbers").last().remove();
            x--;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using class and .last() is to put the button into the person wrapper

To delete, use closest to remove the wrapper the button is in (so have a wrapper for each person)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = 0; //initial count
    $(".add_field_button").on("click",function (e) {
        var $pWrapper = $('<div/>').addClass("person"); //Fields wrapper    
        e.preventDefault();
        x++;
        $pWrapper.append('<button type="button" class="remove_person">REMOVE</button>')
        .append('<div class="names">Name: <input type="text" name="names[]"/></div>')
        .append('<div class="ages">Age: <input type="text" name="ages[]"/></div>')
        .append('<div class="numbers">Number: <input type="text" name="numbers[]"/><br><br></div></div>')
        .appendTo("#input_fields_wrap");
    });

    $("#input_fields_wrap").on("click", ".remove_person", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".person").remove();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>People:</b><br>
<div class="input_fields_wrap" id="input_fields_wrap">
    <button type="button" class="add_field_button">ADD</button>
    <br>
</div>
```